# Is there a clinical definition for the psychological disorder/personality disorder for people who like to get under people’s skin?

Tags: personality, terminology

I have noticed in my 50+ years of life that there are people who take joy (sometimes great joy) out of “getting under” another person’s skin.  Is there a clinical definition for this behavior?  Perhaps it is a personality disorder.

(There is a non-clinical way to describe such a person but civility restrains me).

I have noticed that people who exhibit this behavior seem to be looking for a reaction.  And by seeing a reaction to what they say, they see their control over another person.
It may also be the only way the person knows how to impress others (possibly due to low self-esteem).

I have searched the internet and all I have found so far is information on how to deal with such a person.

Comment: See https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2374/not-all-observations-necessarily-need-a-term-in-psychology

Comment: Not sure what is meant by the comment.  The tags are correct.

Comment: I voted to close as "not framed in psych/neuro"; just linking to a meta discussion about the issue and the reason for my vote.

Comment: How does one 'frame' such a post into the psych/neuro framework?

Comment: See https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2277/why-was-my-question-closed-as-not-framed-in-psychology-or-neuroscience

Comment: I think more information about this person's behavior is needed before making a diagnosis of psychopathy. I have a friend who provokes and likes the attention from reactions. Like Tony said, in and of itself, this is not a characteristic that raises red flags.

Comment: @CouchIssuesTMClinicalCoachin But is your friend doing this “for fun” or “to irritate”.  To use an analogy, one person can push an old lady in front of an oncoming car and another person can push old lady away from oncoming car. They both push old ladies around but their intentions are different.

Comment: Upon reading this, my brain instantly recalled a person with whom I used to work.  After about a year of working with him, I concluded his primary goal at work was to annoy others and to attempt to control them with this behaviour.  Although this was many years ago, your description is so spot on, a mental image of his face instantly popped into mind.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Spot on!  That’s the character I’m taking about.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket [Machiavellianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machiavellianism_(psychology)) is one of the three [Dark Triad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_triad) characteristics and seems to align with the manipulation/controlling characteristic.

Comment: @TonyMobbs Thanks Tony.  The more I read about Machiavellianism, the more I recognize it in certain people.  Sometimes it's overt, but sometimes it is more subtle or masked by other behaviours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking joy in irritating others is unlikely to be classifiable as a personality disorder, however, the [Dark Triad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_triad) describes individuals with disagreeable habits. In combination with other extremely adverse behaviours, it is perhaps classifiable as [Conduct disorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisocial_personality_disorder) or [Narcissistic personality disorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_personality_disorder).

Comment: I see your point. The behavior itself may be part of a disorder and not a disorder in itself.  Is there a succinct term or word for this behavior?

Comment: There are several words that may apply depending upon the extremity of the irritating behaviour.  Candidates may be irritate, torment, provoke, needle, infuriate, grate, annoy, bully, and aggravate.